# I am copying some field data into a newly created table from another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to combine insert some field are hardcoded whilst some field are data from other table into my table. How do I do it.

```
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES('10250', null, null, '1996-07-08', null);

INSERT INTO Orders(OrderID,CustomerID, EmployeeID,ShipperID) 
SELECT CustomerID, EmployeeID, ShipperID 
FROM Customers,Employees, Shippers
WHERE  CustomerID = 34 
   AND EmployeeID = 4 
   AND ShipperID =2;
```

Comment: `Orders(OrderID,CustomerID, EmployeeID,ShipperID)` 4 field and `SELECT CustomerID, EmployeeID, ShipperID ` 3 field. specify or remove `OrderID`

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: Use INSERT to insert a new row. Use UPDATE to update that row.